# Read table from docx file using Apache POI

Tags: java, class, apache-poi, fetch, docx

I am able to read tables from doc file. (see following code)

```java
public String readDocFile(String filename, String str) {
        try {
            InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
            POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(fis);
            HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fs);

            Range range = doc.getRange();
            boolean intable = false;
            boolean inrow = false;

            for (int i = 0; i < range.numParagraphs(); i++) {
                Paragraph par = range.getParagraph(i);
                //System.out.println("paragraph "+(i+1));
                //System.out.println("is in table: "+par.isInTable());
                //System.out.println("is table row end: "+par.isTableRowEnd());
                //System.out.println(par.text());

                if (par.isInTable()) {
                    if (!intable) {//System.out.println("New table creating"+intable);
                        str += "<table border='1'>";
                        intable = true;
                    }
                    if (!inrow) {//System.out.println("New row creating"+inrow);
                        str += "<tr>";
                        inrow = true;
                    }
                    if (par.isTableRowEnd()) {
                        inrow = false;
                    } else {
                        //System.out.println("New text adding"+par.text());
                        str += "<td>" + par.text() + "</td>";
                    }
                } else {
                    if (inrow) {//System.out.println("Closing Row");
                        str += "</tr>";
                        inrow = false;
                    }
                    if (intable) {//System.out.println("Closing Table");
                        str += "</table>";
                        intable = false;
                    }
                    str += par.text() + "<br/>";
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
        }

        return str;
    }
```

Can anyone suggest me how can I do the same with docx file ?
I tried to do that. But could not locate a replacement of 'Range' class.

Please help.

Comment: Did you try looking at the [Apache POI XWPF Table example](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/SimpleTable.java)? At first glance, that should cover you...

Comment: @Gagravarr why not as an answer? :)

Comment: use XWPFDocument.getTableIterator() ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By popular request, promoting a comment to an answer...

In the [Apache POI code examples](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/), you can find the [XWPF SimpleTable example](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/examples/SimpleTable.java)

This shows how to create a simple table, and how to create one with lots of fancy styling.

Assuming you just want a simple table from scratch, in a brand new workbook, then the code you need goes along the lines of:

```
// Start with a new document
XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();

// Add a 3 column, 3 row table
XWPFTable table = doc.createTable(3, 3);

// Set some text in the middle
table.getRow(1).getCell(1).setText("EXAMPLE OF TABLE");

// table cells have a list of paragraphs; there is an initial
// paragraph created when the cell is created. If you create a
// paragraph in the document to put in the cell, it will also
// appear in the document following the table, which is probably
// not the desired result.
XWPFParagraph p1 = table.getRow(0).getCell(0).getParagraphs().get(0);

XWPFRun r1 = p1.createRun();
r1.setBold(true);
r1.setText("The quick brown fox");
r1.setItalic(true);
r1.setFontFamily("Courier");
r1.setUnderline(UnderlinePatterns.DOT_DOT_DASH);
r1.setTextPosition(100);

// And at the end
table.getRow(2).getCell(2).setText("only text");

// Save it out, to view in word
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("simpleTable.docx");
doc.write(out);
out.close();
```

Comment: I want to read tables from docx file but I want to know that these tables are in which paragraphs and where are they located in docx file. Is there any way to get tables from paragraph list?thanks.@Gagravarr

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet uses Apache POI 5.0.0, and it works well when reading docx table data

```
public void readDocxTables(String docxFilePath) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(docxFilePath));
    for(XWPFTable table : doc.getTables()) {
        for(XWPFTableRow row : table.getRows()) {
            for(XWPFTableCell cell : row.getTableCells()) {
                System.out.println("cell text: " + cell.getText());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not Apache POI, but using third party component found it much easier. 
[An example how to get tables from a docx file](http://www.independentsoft.de/jword/tutorial/gettables.html).

Of course, just idea if you do not find solution with the POI,